# Вывод информации о пользователях.

Tags: mysql

Существует пользователь, у которого есть некоторое количество свойств, не больше 40-ка. Как лучше организовать хранение данных в бд и раставить индексы если часто приходится выводить информацию о количестве пользователей имеющих определенное свойство.
Например:

```
пользователи:
умеют плавать(10)
умеют прыгать(90)
умеют ползать(11)
```

**p.s.** кэширование не рассматривать вообще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может подойдёт способ, который я использовал для организации фильтров товара. В вашем случае это примерно так:

1. Таблица пользователей
2. Таблица с названиями свойств
3. Таблица в которой храниться id пользователя и id свойства

В последней таблице может быть сколько угодно строк "id_пользователя <=> id_свойства". Соответственно, если есть какое-то свойство, то по нему легко получить кол-во пользователей, имеющих это самое свойство

Comment: сейчас именно так всё и организовано. вот и хочется узнать какие еще варианты используются для подобных задач и сравнить плюсы минусы

Comment: Пробовал другие варианты, но как-то всё по-индуски получалось. После нескольких проб, остановился на этом. Работает довольно шустро. Выборка количества по определенному свойству заняла 0.0003сек при 10к записей таблице

Answer (score 1):

Самый внятный и масштабируемый способ, это то что предложил [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis). Основное его преимущество в том, что такую же установку привилегий можно организовать и для пользовательских ролей, и потом одним запросом выбирать суммарные свойства пользователя с  учетом свойств установленных для него ролей.

Еще можно писать привилегии в `BLOB`. Если рассматривать вариант, когда у каждого свойства есть свой порядковый номер, то хранить набор таких свойств можно в бинарной последовательности, где каждый установленный бит - это разрешенное пользователю свойство. Получать флаг установленного свойства  можно через битовый сдвиг. Общий набор свойств для пользователя и его ролей можно получить через битовое сложение. Недостаток: неудобно и ненаглядно редактировать все это напрямую через БД.

Также, в случае PHP, можно воспользоваться полем `TEXT`. Генерить в PHP массив свойств и писать в `TEXT` результат `serialize()` этого массива. Соответственно, при чтении восстанавливать массив через `unserialize()`. Недостаток: суммировать разрешенные свойства для пользователей и ролей на уровне запроса к БД не получится.

Comment: если хранить свойства в бинарной последовательности, и выбирать количество пользователей обладающих определенным свойством, в селекте сравнивать по побитовому сдвигу, это дополнительная операция, и для каждого свойства,чтобы получить количество, нужно будет писать отдельный запрос, тогда как при трех таблицах можно выбрать одним запросом несколько свойств и через count(*)

Comment: Если в битмапах хранить, то и SQL собственно не нужен

Comment: @FLK, суть в том чтобы SQL-запросом выбирать всю последовательность, а результат на уровне PHP разносить в массив. При любых вариантах вы будете читать все свойства одним запросом. Делать по запросу на каждое свойство - неоправданные расходы.

Но, впрочем, это всего лишь один из вариантов как хранить свойства в БД. Всеже, более удобный вариант вам предложил @Deonis.